# Link application with contact

Tags: android, mime-types, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

Is it possible to link some application with contact?

I have tried this tutorial - http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/ but seems this isn't what i'm seeking.

If i just add custom fields to some RAW_CONTACT_ID like so:

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.c99.SyncProviderDemo.profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, username);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    try {
        mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can grab this fields with cursor, but this fields are not visible in contact details.

I don't want to make new contact linked to some account. I want just add shortcut to my application in contact details to use it in quick contact badge or directly from contact details - WhatsApp like.

Is there some solution for such situation or maybe someone could point me to right direction?

Comment: did you found the solution. how did you accomplished your task?

Answer (score 0):

This will only be visible in contacts if you add ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE in your raw contact. Only then the Aggregation takes place. Also make sure that the DISPLAY_NAME of the contact you want to link must be same.

Suppose You have a contact named "test"(DISPLAY_NAME) then you have to make the following changes:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = newArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder =ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
operationList.add(builder.build());

operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,"test")
.build());

builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.c99.SyncProviderDemo.profile");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, username);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
operationList.add(builder.build());

try {
    mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also make sure that your **contacts.xml** must have the same android:mimeType i.e
`android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.c99.SyncProviderDemo.profile"`
then only your contact link will be visible...

I hope this helps